# Imputing partially missing dates

Tags: r, date, missing-data, imputation

I have time series data of a clinical trial, in which patients are treated within treatment sequences. Patients can have up to 10 sequences. Each sequence has a start and an end date. In addition, patients have dates for enrollment, before the first sequence starts, and for the last observation, after the last sequence ends.

The problem I have is that some dates are missing completely (NA), and some are partially missing, with the month and the day or only the day missing ("9999-99-99","2010-01-99" or "2010-99-99"). The challenge is now to come up with a method to impute the missing dates, using as much of the available information as possible, and without creating implausible values: Treatment sequences should only start after enrollment; Previous treatment sequence must have ended before the next starts, etc.

I am not looking for a complete solution - It is just that I don't know what type of method I should use to tackle this issue. I'd appreciate your thoughts on this.

Thank you.

Some data to illustrate the problem:

```
time.df= data.frame(id = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",3),rep("C",2)),
               enrolled = c(rep("2010-01-01",4),rep("2010-03-99",3),rep("2010-02-99",2)),
               last.obs = c(rep("2015-03-28",4),rep("2013-99-99",3),rep("2012-12-12",2)),
               start = c("2010-04-22","2011-11-99","2014-99-99","2014-12-01",
                     "2010-03-20","2011-11-12","2013-08-14",
                     "9999-99-99","9999-99-99"),
               end = c("2010-06-28","2013-04-12","2014-06-01","2015-03-99",
                     "9999-99-99","2012-07-08","2013-12-24",
                     "9999-99-99","9999-99-99"))
```

Comment: You could have a look at the `lubridate` package for dates and the `rebus` package for regular expressions.